# How to get add action to execute "after" the post is saved not before

Tags: wordpress, action, addition

I have a plugin that copies "events" - a custom post type - from the parent site to a child site. The copy code works but it looks as though the "add action" is being called before wordpress saves the data on the parent site. See action here:

add_action('publish_event', 'copy_event_to_another_site', 10, 1 );

How can I get the "add action" to execute after wordpress has saved all the relevant data on the parent site before its called - so I can copy the data from the parent across.

UPDATE. The actual post type of "event" is saved but all the other related data is not. So I guess the question is now how to execute the process after all the data has been saved.

UPDATE2.

I found you can use a delay feature

```
add_action('publish_event', 'b4w_update_after_one_minute', 10, 1 );

add_action('b4w_delay_copy', 'copy_to_child_site', 10, 1 );

function b4w_update_after_one_minute() {
  wp_schedule_single_event( time() + 60, 'b4w_delay_copy');
}


function copy_to_child_site($parent_id){
  // copy code goes here
}
```

The problem is that the function "copy_to_child_site" needs the parent post ID passed to it. Using the delay I dont see how I can pass that parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use post meta to save extra data and use 2 hooks (updated_post_meta, added_post_meta)

[updated_post_meta](http://hookr.io/actions/updated_post_meta/), an action that gets called after the data is updated in the database.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you can pass it through your single_event :

```
 function b4w_update_after_one_minute() {
     global $post;
     $id = $post->ID;
     wp_schedule_single_event( time()+100 , 'b4w_delay_copy', array($id));
    }
```